# Hyphen or en-dash

Tags: style, editing, punctuation, titles

What is the correct dash usage when naming a title?

I have an essay with the title:

> *The success factors for successful e-commerce - A Linux-based e-commerce platform from an economic perspective*

What is the correct dash usage between e-commerce *and* A Linux...?
And should there be a space between e and A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither; it should be an em-dash or a colon. A hyphen is used to connect a compound (*a must-read book, Linux-based*) and an en-dash connects a range of numbers (*1966–69*). I prefer the colon if you must have a subtitle. If you use the em-dash, I prefer spaces around it, but that's up to the house style of where you're publishing.

Also, titles should be in title case.

> The Success Factors for Successful E-Commerce: A Linux-Based E-Commerce Platform from an Economic Perspective

Or

> The Success Factors for Successful E-Commerce — A Linux-Based E-Commerce Platform from an Economic Perspective

I don't understand your second question, as there is nowhere in the title where *e* is next to *A*.

Comment: I am *guessing* the poster meant "Should there be a space between [the] e [at the end of 'commerce' and the dash] and [between the dash and the] A", which you answered with your preference and a note that house styles may differ on that subject.

Comment: I meant if there should be space between the main titles end and the dash, with the subtitles beginning.
That's E-Commerce ending with e.

Comment: What is the correct usage if the "subtitle" was specifying the title. As this is a report. I use main title The Success Factors for Successful E-Commerce. After the main title I input Report to specify the paper as a report. What should connect E-Commerce & Report?
Or as a whole as from the start. Main title, subtitle and Report after the subtitle.

Comment: @nicoX Why do you have to say that it's a report? Would someone otherwise confuse it with a tomato? Unless there's some compelling contextual reason to label it Report — for example, in a bound book of long pieces of writing, or a magazine of reprints, a reader might reasonably wonder whether yours might be a blog post, a white paper, a dissertation, a rant, or an editorial — adding "Report" is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum The label was for the *.doc file name, not the actual title name in the paper. This is just so I can distinguish between my files, so I know what is what.

Comment: @nicoX The file name is irrelevant; it can have whatever characters you like. You can label your file *Ralph-The&Sentinent@Head$Of%Lettuce^.doc* if it helps you keep track of it. We're only discussing the title of the piece as others see it.

Comment: In British English, the en-dash takes most of the duties the em-dash has in American English. I have no idea whether this is relevant to the questioner.

Comment: The Oxford Style Guide actually recommends an en-dash flanked with two spaces over an em-dash and no spaces.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [APA style guide](https://dissertation.laerd.com/style-guides-for-dissertation-titles-p2.php), "A subtitle should be separated using a colon or em dash (i.e., — and not the shorter - en dash) and then a single space (i.e., Title: Subtitle OR Title — Subtitle)."

Personally, I find the Oxford Style Guide recommendation of an en-dash far more aesthetically pleasing.